# node.js https request error event issue

Tags: node.js, https, callback, econnreset

I'm using node.js (10.23) https lib to send request to a 3rd party web service. Everything appears ok, but recently I found a weird issue which has confused me.

Here is the code:

```
var https = require('https');        

function callWebService(requestOpts,body,accessToken,callback){
    var options = {
        host: requestOpts.host, 
        path: requestOpts.path,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),  
            'Authorization':'Bearer '+accessToken
        }
    };

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        logger.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        logger.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

        if(res.statusCode!='200') {
            var error = new Error("Web service call failed");
            return callback(error);           
        } else {
            logger.log('web service call success');
            return callback();
        }   
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        logger.error('call web service,error occurs: ' + e.message);
        return callback(e);     
    });
    req.write(body);
    req.end();
}
```

Sometimes (not every time) I can see both success and errors in the logs, the error is 'read ECONNRESET'. I don't really know why this occurs.

From my view, a http(s) transaction is one request and one response, how could it be one request, but get possible two responses.

And I checked node.js official document, it says

> If any error is encountered during the request (be that with DNS
>   resolution, TCP level errors, or actual HTTP parse errors) an 'error'
>   event is emitted on the returned request object.

So I guess that maybe the http(s) request and response work fine and the error happens on 'TCP level', but why is the call back is called twice?

Comment: Is it possible to add the complete log you got after one request (which is causing the problem of course)?

Comment: this is full error log,it's very simple.error occurs: read ECONNRESET
{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }

Comment: Did some research on this issue, seems it's node's bug,but not for sure.https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5119

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5360

Comment: Yeah. The issue is because of lack of TLS support in IIS servers. But still this does not resolve the issue of 2 responses. Perhaps, I didn't put my request properly. I was more interested in the order of appearance of logs rather than the full log message.